# azure AD B2C, java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-ad-b2c

I have searched a lot regarding the support for Spring boot, REST implementation with  Azure AD B2C Security but couldn't find anything (other than Azure AD applications or a .net application).

Does that mean that Azure AD B2C does not support java / spring boot application?

If it is possible, has somebody tried it and let me know the configuration changes need to be made from a Azure AD web App to Azure AD B2C Webb APP.

Looking forward for your support.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does :)

for both Spring Authorisation Server and Resource Server. My recent implementation was Resource Server (best if you just need to secure REST API and your app only consumes tokens, other front-end app takes care of login redirections etc.), a great tutorial about spring security with oAuth2 you can find at [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt).
My security config based on tutorial was:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    @EnableScheduling
    @RequiredArgsConstructor   
    public class SecurityResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${b2c.client-id}")
    private String resourceId;

    private final KeyUtilHandler keyUtilHandler;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices customTokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {

        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setVerifierKey(keyUtilHandler.stringPublicKey());

        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.resourceId(resourceId);
        configurer.tokenServices(customTokenServices());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

    }
}
```

If you provide resource id (azure client id) and verifier key (setVerifierKey) in token converter - Spring will take care of adding to chain a filter that verifies signature and basic claims from token. Thats all about security config. The other thing is that azure doesn't provide key in token, you can find proper public key by key id ("kid" in token). Azure also provide nessecary values to encode key, they can be found in json object at endpoint created for every b2c tenant -

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant name}/discovery/v2.0/keys?p={your sign in sign up policy}

for example: https://login.microsoftonline.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_sign_in

```
{
  "keys": [
    {"kid":"X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk","nbf":1493763266,"use":"sig","kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"tVKUtcx_n9rt5afY_2WFNvU6PlFMggCatsZ3l4RjKxH0jgdLq6CScb0P3ZGXYbPzXvmmLiWZizpb-h0qup5jznOvOr-Dhw9908584BSgC83YacjWNqEK3urxhyE2jWjwRm2N95WGgb5mzE5XmZIvkvyXnn7X8dvgFPF5QwIngGsDG8LyHuJWlaDhr_EPLMW4wHvH0zZCuRMARIJmmqiMy3VD4ftq4nS5s8vJL0pVSrkuNojtokp84AtkADCDU_BUhrc2sIgfnvZ03koCQRoZmWiHu86SuJZYkDFstVTVSR0hiXudFlfQ2rOhPlpObmku68lXw-7V-P7jwrQRFfQVXw"}
  ]
}
```

You need "n" and "e" values to encode valid key for your client app. There are ready libraries, but you can write your own implementation. I also used rest template to get json and extract values. According to microsoft documentation keys can be changed from time to time so you might want to schedule method.

```
public class KeyUtilHandler {

    @Value("${b2c.key-url}")
    private String keyUrl;

    @Value("${b2c.sign-up-or-in-user-flow}")
    private String signUpOrInUserFlow;

    @Value("${b2c.tenant}")
    private String tenant;

    private String eValue;
    private String nValue;

    public String stringPublicKey(){

        setAzureKeys();

        byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(nValue);
        BigInteger modulusInt = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);

        byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(eValue);
        BigInteger exponentInt = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

        KeyFactory keyFactory;

        RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulusInt, exponentInt);

        String encodedStringKey = null;

        {
            try {
                keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

                RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);

                byte [] encodedKey = publicKey.getEncoded();

                encodedStringKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedKey);

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return String.format("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----%s-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
                    , encodedStringKey);

    }

    private void setAzureKeys (){

        String resolvedKeyUrl = String.format(keyUrl, tenant, signUpOrInUserFlow);

        RestTemplate azureKeys = new RestTemplate();
        AzureKeySetDto result = azureKeys.getForObject(resolvedKeyUrl, AzureKeySetDto.class);
        if (Objects.isNull(result.getKeys())) {
            throw new UnableToGetResourceException();
        }
        Map<String, String> keyMap = result.getKeys().stream()
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        eValue = keyMap.get("e");
        nValue = keyMap.get("n");
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = TWENTY_HOURS_IN_MILIS)
    private void renewKeys(){
            setAzureKeys();
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows how can I get the public key. but I need private key. So is there a way to get the private key?

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://www.lionmint.com/en/spring-boot-security-with-azure-b2c-2/) shows how to use the Azure AD B2C (Azure Active Directory) to secure a Spring Boot web service backend. You can find full code in the GitHub repository. Have a look at this doc and hope it will be helpful!

Comment: Thanks but using a Id_token is written almost everywhere. I want to use the EasyAuth flow.

Comment: Blogpost is no longer available it seems, but code is still on github: https://github.com/lionmint/spring-angular-azureb2c